# Create an even shadow on a full-width element

Tags: html, css

When a box-shadow is applied to an element the corners are less "thick" than the middle because they don't have shadow on both sides.  This creates an odd effect on full width elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/kevincox/6FhYe/18/

If you look at that example you will see that the edges are lighter.  If the "banner" is at the top of a page you can spread it and shift it up but that doesn't work for the middle of the page as you can see the top.

I was wondering if anyone had a solution with no images and preferably cross-browser but I can deal with vendor prefixes for a bit.  Is there something like a separate horizontal and vertical stretch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One trick that seems to work is setting negative horizontal margins on the element, so that its ends extend outside the page, and adjusting the padding to compensate.  Using [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevincox/6FhYe/18/) as an example, [try changing the CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/CGRLp/) to:

```
h1 {
    margin: 20px -20px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #AFA;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peter/43eRa/1/)

Each number in the shadows represents the following

1. The horizontal offset of the shadow, positive means the shadow will
   be on the right of the box, a negative offset will put the shadow on
   the left of the box.
2. The vertical offset of the shadow, a negative one means the
   box-shadow will be above the box, a positive one means the shadow
   will be below the box.
3. The blur radius (optional), if set to 0 the shadow will be sharp,
   the higher the number, the more blurred it will be.
4. The spread radius (optional), positive values increase the size of
   the shadow, negative values decrease the size. Default is 0 (the
   shadow is same size as blur).
5. Color

Comment: That doesn't really look very much like the original shadow at all: it's way broader and washed out.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen no it doesn't that's pretty obvious but it's cross browser compliant, and I explained the usage of all parts of those styles. The 1px he has there is causing the horizontal offset on the edges. So my example uses all parts of the box styles with a 0px offset. I enlarged the radius to illustrate a point.

Comment: If he changes his style to `box-shadow: 10px 0 10px black;` he can clearly see how the offset is affecting the shadow.

Comment: Yes, and if you change it to `box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;` you can clearly see just how little effect the OP's 1px offset has.  Your use of a large spread radius _does_, admittedly, hide the corners of the shadow by pushing them off the screen, but it does that at the cost of a significant change in the general appearance of the shadow.

Answer (score 1):

Applying border-radius also fixes this issue (but obviously it depends on whether you want that in your design).

```
h1 {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #AFA;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 10px black;
}
```